# I have created a graphite rpm, and it is making an error stating "perl(Python::Serialise::Pickle)" error while installing

Tags: installation, rpm

```
    rpm -Uhv Graphite-0.9.1-2.x86_64.rpm 
    error: Failed dependencies:  
    perl(Python::Serialise::Pickle)
    is needed by Graphite-0.9.1-2.icontrol.com.x86_64
```

I'm getting this error while installing the rpm, do you have any suggestions regarding how to solve this issue on centos 6 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `yum install Graphite-0.9.1-2.x86_64.rpm`? You say you built the rpm yourself. Where did you get that perl module from in the first place? CPAN?

Comment: I made the rpm using the existing(working) source code available. So what this error mean ? perl(Python::Serialise::Pickle) 
Thank you.
This error mean I didnt make the rpm properly ? I mean the spec file ?

Comment: It means RPM detected that your packaged code requires that module and you don't have an rpm installed that provides that module. Where did that perl module come from? Do you have it on your system? Is it something bundled with graphite? (What is graphite anyway?)